# How to install fingerprint scanner

Tags: keyboard

I have a Lenovo T440p and I previously had the fingerprint scanner installed on Mint 19.3.

I tried to reinstall it using the same sudo commands and it came back with a repository not found message.

Has anyone tried installing fingerprint scanner with elementary os? If so, how did you get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give some details on the ' repository not found message.'?

Comment: eone4life@eone4life-T440p:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
[sudo] password for e********:          
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

Comment: The `add-apt-repository` command is not included in elementary by default. Run `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` first. This will also install the `add-apt-repository` command. After that, run your `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui` command again.

Comment: Thank you @VladPop I followed your instructions and it worked.